# Find matching values in different row of dataframe with group_by and str_detect

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a table:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(group = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"),
   code = c("foo", "bar", "fuz", "baz", "fiz", "boz"),
   child_code = c("bar", "", "baz", "", "biz", ""))
```

I'd like to `group_by` `group` and then search for the `code` in the `child_code`column to get something like this:

| group | code | child_code | code_in_child_code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | foo | bar | FALSE |
| a | bar |  | TRUE |
| b | fuz | baz | FALSE |
| b | baz |  | TRUE |
| c | fiz | biz | FALSE |
| c | boz |  | FALSE |

I've tried:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(code_in_child_code = str_detect(child_code, code))
```

But (I suppose obviously) that's just looking for the `child_code` in the same row's `code` column. I want to seach the `child_code` column for the any value in the whole group's codes.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an answer:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(codes = paste(code, collapse = "|"), 
    code_in_child_code = str_detect(child_code, codes))
```

Seems fairly facile now - of course I needed to get the codes in the same row as the value I was searching for. The values TRUE and FALSE are the "wrong" way round in this answer, but it's as useful either way.

Comment: Negate your logical values to get them the correct way by doing: `!str_detect(child_code, codes)`